# Does This Hierarchy work with ListView? Getting NoReverseMatch Error

Tags: django, django-views

I'm running into an issue debugging the following error:

> Reverse for 'tasks' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['customer/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/tasks/$']

However, I'm pretty certain that my url parameters are correct and without typos. The url and page worked fine with a function based view, the problem started when I changed to a ListView.

Template:

```
<a href="{% url 'customerportal:tasks' object.slug %}" class="nav-link">
```

I also tried:

```
<a href="{% url 'customerportal:tasks' slug=object.slug %}" class="nav-link">
<a href="{% url 'customerportal:tasks' slug=object.slug|slugify %}" class="nav-link">
```

DetailView - passing slug param to url

```
class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
model = Project
template_name = 'customerportal/customer_portal.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    if not self.object.access_verification(request.user):
        raise PermissionDenied()
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

My ListView (errors):

```
class TaskListView(ListView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'customerportal/tasks.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=self.kwargs['customer_portal'])
        return Task.objects.filter(project=self.project.id)
```

URLs:

```
path('<slug:slug>/', ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='customer_portal'),
path('<slug:customer_portal>/tasks/', TaskListView.as_view(), name='tasks'),
```

I've confirmed that I'm passing the right slug by printing it. The slug parameter is from a parent directory as seen in the urls.py above. I'm guessing ListView doesn't work this way? If not is there a way I could maintain this structure, or do I have to switch back to a function based view in order to get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 things to sort out:

1. your error message says that there is a path that looks similar to this:

```
path('customer/<slug:customer_portal>/tasks/', TaskListView.as_view(), name='tasks'),
```

but your paths do not match that pattern of the error message - maybe you edited the paths after the error appeared.

2. the error type "... arguments '('',)' ..." always means that the parameter in your {% url ... %} statement is empty. In your case that would mean object.slug is empty
   Please check what you handover to the template as object.slug

Comment: I thought object.slug may have been empty as well. So to test I printed it to console from get_context_data and that worked. I also put {{ object.slug }} in a random div and the slug prints there as well. So it's there, but for some reason it's missing only when it's passed as a url parameter. I can only get it to show in the url parameter if I do slug=object.slug but then I get the error Reverse for 'tasks' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'test'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['customer/(?P<customer_portal>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/tasks/$']

Comment: Sure that it is the only url on that template? Maybe there is another one with a typo? I have never seen that error message in other circumstances.

Comment: I believe so, yes. Because when I hardcode the slug parameter without changing anything else, then everything works fine. For example {% url 'customerportal:tasks' 'test' %} works, everything loads without error. But once I change 'test' back to object.slug the error comes up again. I should also note everything was working fine when I was using FBV's and manually passing the slug through context. I didn't run into this problem until I switched to classes. I'll edit in the class that's passing the slug param in case something is wrong there, ProjectDetailView. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your time and help, but I decided to try a different approach. I went with using get_absolute_url instead and it works fine now. Plus I guess this approach is more conventional anyway. Thanks though.